# IBInspectable suggestion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uikit

Is it possible to have value suggestions on a variable that is IBInspectable?

I want to suggest a list strings to an user (same behaviour seen when trying to select an image name).

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible. You might want to [file a feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Thanks @jtbandes. Just filed an improvement to Apple. Cheers